# Python MySQLdb : Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 1

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, duplicates

I am getting this error when I run my program in Python. 
Here's the table of my database :

```
Field           Type            Collation       Null        Key     Default     
articleCode   varchar(25)    latin1_swedish_ci   NO         UNI                                                
dateReceived   datetime            NULL          NO         MUL     0000-00-00 00:00:00                  
s100RSD        datetime            NULL          YES                0000-00-00 00:00:00        
remarks        longtext      latin1_swedish_ci   YES
```

And to simplify the problem of my program, I will isolate the part of the program that makes an error, here:

```
import MySQLdb

def main():
    dateReceived = '2011-10-07 01:06:30'
    articleCode = 'name'
    s100rsd = '2011-10-07 01:06:30'
    remark_text = 'This is a remark'
    db = MySQLdb.connect('server', 'user', 'passwd', 'table_name', port)
    cur = db.cursor()
    db_query = cur.execute("INSERT INTO tblS100CurrentListing (articleCode, dateReceived, s100RSD, remarks) VALUES ('articleCode', 'dateReceived', 's100rsd', 'remark_text')")
    cur.close()
    db.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here's the error that I get : _mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 1")

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: i should provide full db schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be inserting constants into the database, not your actual values. Instead, try something similar to;

```
db_query = cur.execute("INSERT INTO tblS100CurrentListing " +
    "(articleCode, dateReceived, s100RSD, remarks) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", 
    (articleCode, dateReceived, s100rsd, remark_text))
```

Comment: Alright I think, this is the one that I am looking for. Thanks, I will try to revised my query, and update here again. Thanks!

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but still I get "Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 1"

Comment: Joachim, I now figure out what's the problem, I am having duplicate primary key every time I run the program. My problem now is, my primary key is set to auto_increment but everytime I insert a new row, the id set is always '2147483647' that's why Im getting "Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 1". How can I handle this one? thanks!

Comment: I now fix all the error. It's just a schema problem. And now the program is running okay! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the limit of Key. If it is INTEGER, 2147483647 is the limit. You can choose something like BIGINT or the one bigger than INTEGER. All records after 2147483647 will be tried to write on value 2147483647. So this is why you are having this problem. Change it with BIGINT / LARGEINT or something like this.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unique key on field *"articleCode"* preventing MySQL to have two records in this column with the same content. Seems like you already inserted one on the first program run.

Remove previously inserted record with *articleCode = 'name'* OR remove UNIQUE KEY on *articleCode* field OR try to insert different value of articleCode.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for that help! It also helps! I will now try to reprogram my codes.

Answer (score 0):

After correcting the code as described in other answers, you should modify the table in order to reset its auto_increment counter.

```
ALTER TABLE tblS100CurrentListing auto_increment=1
```

should reset the counter to the lowest possible value.

Removing or repairing the erroneous values from the table is required; otherwise the change won't have any effect.

Besides, is it really needed to insert a field which is set to auto_increment? Or is this part of a restore process? Otherwise, the two things are redundant: either you get the data automatically or you insert them. Both can (as seen) lead to conflicts.